# Trying to query posts with the tags of current post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a website with multiple post relations. For cross-referencing between the posts I'm using wordpress tags. Now, when I'm on a post that has more than one tag, I want to query all posts that have BOTH the tags. So current post has `'tag1'` and `'tag2'`, there should be a list of posts that only have both of these tags

Refer to the code below to see my non working solution. I figured it would be a good idea to get a list of the current tag ID's. For this I used the standard solution provided by the Wordpress codex, then I created a custom function that could be used in the query. Unfortunately this does not seem like the right solution, the function listtags does output the ID's as expected.

```
    <?php

    function list_tags(){
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->term_id . ' ';
      }
    }

    $listtags = list_tags();
    echo $listtags . ' ';


    $tag_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'les',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'tag__and'  => array( $post_tag ),

    ) );
    // The Loop
    if ( $tag_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $tag_query->have_posts() ) {
            $tag_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="les-container" style="background-color: red; height:200px;">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row posts-align">

                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php the_content(); ?>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }?>
```

the `list_tags();` function seems to work properly as it outputs the tags as expected. However when inserting it in the query it doesn't seem to work. It just outputs all posts, regardless of the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a working solution. Hope this is of help to someone.

**Code:**

```
<?php

    $tags = array();
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $tags[] = $tag->term_id;
        }
    }

    $tag_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'     =>  'les',
        'order'         =>  'ASC',
        'tag__and'      =>  $tags,
        'post_parent'   =>  0,
    ) );

    // The Loop
    if ( $tag_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $tag_query->have_posts() ) {
        $tag_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="les-container" style="background-color: red; height:200px;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row posts-align">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

tag_slug__and is for Slugs. tag__and is for ids. You can find more info here - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp_query-arguments-categories-and-tags--cms-23070

Comment: Also, I don't see $post_tag as a variable. You have $posttags = get_the_tags();

Comment: Hi, thanks! I'm aware of the tag__and for ID's, this is what I'm using (or trying to use). Regarding your second comment, the variable is indeed wrong. This is the part I'm struggling with.